# error: the following arguments are required:

Tags: arguments, maildir

I'm trying to run a [github script](https://github.com/bluebird75/maildir2mbox/tree/master) in VS code to convert maildir emails to mbox. I have the script and the folder with the maildir in a folder on C: drive. When I run the script it comes back with

```bash
PS C:\hello> & C:/Users/stu/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/hello/maildir2mbox.py
usage: maildir2mbox.py [-h] [-r] maildir_path mbox_filename
maildir2mbox.py: error: the following arguments are required: maildir_path, mbox_filename
```

I think I have to define the target mailder and mbox folders but I'm at a loss to how to do it.

I've tried putting paths at a few places but in reality I'm clueless.

Comment: Any help would be most grateful
Kind Regards
Stu

Answer (score 0):

As you thought, you would need to provide the target Maildir and output file path.
The Maildir folder should contains `cur` and/or `new` folders. For example:

```bash
& python c:/hello/maildir2mbox.py c:/hello/.one_maildir_folder my-mbox-output
```

Works with file structure:

```bash
c:/hello/.
│   maildir2mbox.py
│
├───.one_maildir_folder
│   ├───cur
│   │       1464003587.H805375P95754.test, S=20238_2, S
│   │
│   ├───new
│   └───tmp
└───.one_maildir_folder.sub
    ├───cur
    ├───new
    └───tmp
```

See `python maildir2mbox.py --help`

```
usage: maildir2mbox.py [-h] [-r] maildir_path mbox_filename

positional arguments:
  maildir_path   path to the existing maildir (containing new, cur, tmp) subdirectories
  mbox_filename  target filename in the mbox format. If the mailbox already exists, new messages are appended to it.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -r, --recurse  Process all mail folders included in maildir_path. An equivalent structure is recreated in the mbox
                 format
```

Comment: So how would I do that? The maldir folder is called maildir  and the output folder inside it is mbox

Comment: This is just a python program taking two args: Your maildir folder and your output path.

Comment: You could try `& C:/Users/stu/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/hello/maildir2mbox.py c:/hello/maildir c:/hello/mbox/output.mbox`

Comment: Thank you massively for that. Works but now I can't import thee file. But your bit works

Comment: was glad to help!